# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet Exception

Tags: java, spring

I'm using **Spring 4.0.4 release** and Tomcat server in **Eclipse** IDE, the jar that contains the servlet dispatcher (**spring-webmvc-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar**) is imported but i'm getting this :

```js
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:536)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:148)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1127)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1066)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5409)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5707)
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1702)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1692)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

these are my configuration Files :

1- Beans:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


 
 <context:component-scan base-package="auth.presentation" />

 <bean id="v"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>
 
 
</beans>
```

2- WEB.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MonPFE</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
 
  <welcome-file-list>
   
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Counting on your experience to help me fix it, Thanks.

Comment: how did you compile the code? was it working earlier? check your build path and deployment assembly in eclipse

Comment: Well I have access to the index.jsp, but the redirection to other jsp is where the error pulls up , even when i try to execute the other jsp by itself it raises the same error . In another project the same method works just fine

Comment: try mvn clean install and reset your server in eclipse before trying again

Comment: Okay, I fixed. I imported the jar in a Local Lib folder and it did recognize the DispatcherServlet.Class . Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: that means your build path was wrong. happy to help